# Parse error using generated source map with Firefox Developer and Webpack+Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, webpack

I am getting this error with Firefox Developer using Angular+Typescript+(Angular-built-in Webpack).

```
Source map error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    Resource URL: http://localhost:8080/myApp/main.bundle.js
    Source Map URL: main.bundle.js.map
```

In main.ts there is the required hint for Firefox:
*//# sourceMappingURL=main.bundle.js.map*

Source maps are generated fine (it's working with Chrome) and I can open them with browser. Content is like:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["/Users/.../src/$_gendir lazy","/Users/.../src/app/.../my-detail.component.ts",
```

Comment: I am seeing this also, except on line 3, column 1.  It is only occurring in my angular code, which generates external map files (AOT 4.4.6).